# How to cause Low Memory Condition on Android

Tags: android, android-debug

How can I cause a Low Memory Condition on an Android device so that my Activity is destroyed and the associated Application class receives onTrimMemory() while my application is in the background. I am having issues in my app related to recovery from being killed by the Android OS, when in the background, and want to be able to step through the code in the debugger, but I can't regularly generate this condition, particularly when connected to the debugger :)

Thank You,
Gary

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it:
 In your device: 
Go to Settings -> Developer options and check "Dont keep activities". 
This will kill your activity as soon it goes in the background.

Comment: Thx, I was able to catch other issues after activating this option

Answer (score 1):

You can usually trigger this by throwing your app into the background, and then launching 10-20 apps (depending on the device). This will eventually cause your process to be terminated, which I would assume would be preceded by the `onTrimMemory()` callback.

Comment: I am able to create this condition by launching a bunch of apps and then when I restart my app, the onCreate() method doesn't get called and the app just hangs. I've put break points in onCreate()/onRestart()/onStart()/onResume() and they all get activated when I don't have too many apps started in the foreground, but once this condition occurs, nothing happens anymore. Also, once the application is put in the background, the Eclipse break points no longer seem to be triggering.  Any thoughts how to proceed?

Comment: The debugger gets slow as hell in that situation. I'd honestly just start doing some debug logging for that case rather than actual step-through debugging.

Answer (score -2):

While your app is on foreground, you can kill cached processes via shell

```
adb shell am kill-all
```

then leave your application (make it go background), soon it will receive a `onTrimMemory()` callback.

This happens because system thinks too many apps are dying and that should be a low memory situation.